# Django git conflict affecting url.py

Tags: django, git, url, migration, commit

I'm having a conflict with url.py after making a commit and migration to git. My url.py files have errors I can no longer view the page. How do I fix this conflict, I only need the changes I made, the other changes from other user are not even needed.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^clients$', views.clients,name='clients'),
```

<<<<<<< HEAD

```
url(r'^musicplanet$', views.musicplanet_index,name='musicplanet'),
url(r'^musicplanet_index$', views.music_post_1,name='musicplanet_index'),
```

=======

```
url(r'^musicplanet$',views.musicplanet_index,name='musicplanet_index'),
url(r'^musicplanet_index$', views.music_post_1,name='music_post_1'),
url(r'^mj_index$', views.mj_index,name='mj_index'),
```

->>>>>>> ec8432a416b3ea08176045749ed674f3edfb2ab6

```
url(r'^music_post_1$', views.music_post_1,name='music_post_1'),
url(r'^music_post_2$', views.music_post_2,name='music_post_2'),
```

So I don't need these urls because they don't even work. I just tried commenting them out, but then I would get errors in the view.py.

```
url(r'^musicplanet$',views.musicplanet_index,name='musicplanet_index'),
url(r'^musicplanet_index$', views.music_post_1,name='music_post_1'),
url(r'^mj_index$', views.mj_index,name='mj_index'),
```

Comment: delete the unwanted lines of code, including the `>>>>>>>` and `=======` and save the file - you should be good to go

Comment: Yea, did that for url.py then had errors in view.py. Deleted those lines in view.py then had another error that a module was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application specific issue.  Merging, and merge conflicts, should be covered in any decent git tutorial.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

No one here can really tell you which merge is correct, as it completely depend on your application.

When you have changes to the same file in the same location, in the same commit time then git might not know what to do, and will require that you manually resolve the conflict.  To resolve it, you should remove the lines containing `<<<<`, `====` and `>>>>`.  They are there to show you what that current branch says the commit should be, and what the other branch says the commit should be.